# Shapely and finding overlapping using shape bounds

Tags: python, geospatial, shapely, wkt

Is there any way in Shapely to calculate overlap of different types of geometries using shape bounds (shapely.bounds) ??.

Like for example: If I have multiple geometry types such as "Linestring", "Polygon", "Rectangle", "Circle" as shown below.

LINESTRING(8.461071252822878 48.998180249615714,8.461210727691652 48.9980042741315,8.461409211158754 48.99803243025074,8.46152186393738 48.9982189641388)

POLYGON((8.460153937339784 48.997761426942276,8.460153937339784 48.998500523401574,8.46251964569092 48.998500523401574,8.46251964569092 48.997761426942276,8.460153937339784 48.997761426942276)))

And I want to check whether these shapes overlap each other using bounds of geometry

Comment: looks like a good answer here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/251812/returning-percentage-of-area-of-polygon-intersecting-another-polygon-using-shape

Comment: Do you mean an intersection of bounding boxes of two geometry objects? If so, does the following code answer your question? `from shapely.geometry import box; result = box(*line.bounds).intersection(box(*polygon.bounds))`